# MS Access 2016 auto-sync with SharePoint list on open by VBA

Tags: microsoft-access, sharepoint

I have an Access database linked to a Sharepoint list.  Users will often work on the Access database offline, and catch changes locally.  When online again, the user has to manually click reconnect to tables as showing below:

[image]

Then manually click the synchronize ribbon as showing below:

[[image]}[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVOrW.png)

I am thinking about using VBA to automate these two manual steps.  For instance, auto-connect tables and sync database on open, or similar solutions.  I thought this would be straightforward because many users need this, since Access is a good offline front-end solution for a server database.  But I have searched for hours and still found nothing relevant.  Can anyone help me with this?